# My logs appear only an hour after the actual request on Google App Engine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, logging

To clarify: There are several problems I'm facing here, the most annoying of which is that my app engine logs appear very late in the admin console. I think that they may be related, which is why I'm grouping them together.

I was testing my app after uploading to Google App Engine about two hours ago, and I was tweaking the code and re-deploying. I use the Eclipse plugin and it says deployed successfully. I did not change the version number at first, and apparently all my changes were not being reflected on the server at all. I found out because my logs showed the old build number.

At this point in time, my logs were being updated real-time, and I could see logs from requests that took place seconds ago.

Anyway, I figured that I needed to change version numbers, so I did that and re-deployed, and made the new version default. After this my logs remained empty, even though I was testing my app continuously. And none of the logs of any of the versions showed the latest requests.

I checked my logs about half an hour back, and *now* it shows me the logs for the requests I was making then. Any requests I made at that point in time didn't show either - apparently I'll have to wait another hour for them to show.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there something about the App Engine mechanism I don't understand?

This sounds odd, I know. And I couldn't find anything about it on Google.

Problem 1: Described above.

Problem 2: Do I need to change version numbers anytime I make even a tiny change?

Problem 3: When I make changes to a servlet while testing on the local dev server, it takes approximately 3-4 minutes to reflect those changes when I test the app, even if I stop and restart the server. JSP changes reflect immediately.

Answer (score 1):

1. I see the same behavior: On the initial deployment of an app, log messages seemed to appear real-time, but after a couple of days and lots of deployments, I see delays of up to 30 minutes. Known issue, apparently: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3338.
2. Not required. After deployment, changed code without changes to the version number is immediately available on AppEngine.

Comment: For 2 : Changes I make don't seem to reflect unless I change version numbers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @raghavesethi That's almost certainly a browser caching issue, not a server-side one.

Answer (score 0):

Item 3 sounds like a browser caching issue. Does a forced reload (ctrl-shift-r on firefox) refresh your stale servlet pages?